# Jil serializer as MVC default, don't accept "json" ContentType

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, jil

Does any one know if Jil can accept `ContentType: 'application/json'` in the http call to the API?

From what I see it can only accept `ContentType:x-www-formencoded`

An example of what don't work for me, the object received in the controller is null.
This is the JS call

```
 var request = $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: commad,
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
```

This is the obj content:

```
{"SessionToken":"65e2be91-a455-0ef3-0ba0-c2dd2c281ecc","ClientType":1,"OfferType":1,"DeviceInfo":{"Width":1080,"Height":1920}}
```

Now, in the MVC controller this is the method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<ActionResult> GetUserOffers([FromBody]OffersRequestInfo obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    CampaignLogic logic = new CampaignLogic();
    Task<ActionResult> res = logic.GetOffers(obj);
    return res;
}
```

the obj parameter received as null when using Jil, with Newtonsoft it is holding the value from the request.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please giva a [MCVE]. Thank you!

Comment: I edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next line should be added to the constractor of the JilFormatter

```
  SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

More explanation on how to implement Jil as the default mvc serializer:
[Here](http://blog.developers.ba/replace-json-net-jil-json-serializer-asp-net-web-api/)